# Build error after integrating Jetpack Navigation to existing Android project

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-navigation, build-error

I'm trying to use Navigation Components in one of my activities and while trying to build my project I'm receiving this error:

`.../.gradle/caches/transforms-3/61b9b29ef6aaf7fe551e73466a9c3105/transformed/material-1.7.0/res/values/values.xml:7368:4:`

`Duplicate value for resource 'attr/animationMode' with config 'DEFAULT' and product ''.`

`Resource was previously defined here: ...-mergeDevDebugResources-87:/values/values.xml:17777:`

`Caused by: com.android.aaptcompiler.ResourceCompilationException: Failed to compile values resource file ../build/intermediates/incremental/devDebug/mergeDevDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml`

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not add resource (com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@3f82a8ef) to table.`

nav version = 2.5.3

minSdk = 21

targetSdk = 33

I'm having trouble understanding the error message so it is hard for me to troubleshoot. The duplicate value seems to be in a Material library file and I am unable to locate where it was supposedly predefined. I have added all the necessary dependencies for Jetpack Navigation and I've set up the nav graph and
NavHostFragment in the resources directory and activity's XML file, respectively, according to this [google doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#groovy).

Comment: [Nothing in any AndroidX library](https://cs.android.com/search?ss=androidx&q=animationMode) declares an attribute called `animationMode`. Your error seems to be coming from the [Material Components Library](https://m2.material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started) 1.7.0 (which `navigation-ui` only happens to pull in as a dependency). Does adding the Material dependency directly also cause this error? This seems like a conflict between that library and something else you are using (do *you* define an `animationMode` attribute?).

Comment: Yeah actually I found that a third party library I'm using also declares the `animationMode` attribute. What I don't understand is why it's complaining about it now and why adding Navigation would cause this error. I'm trying to fork the library and change the attribute name directly but I'm having trouble getting my dependency to work in my project. I used jitpack.io to create it from a release on GitHub. It seems like this is just a work-around though and maybe not necessary?

Comment: As soon as I add this line 
`implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.3"`
The error reappears. Same with the Java implementation of that library.

Comment: Like my comment said, `navigation-ui` depends on the Material Components Library.

Comment: Oh, right.. I don't need that library for my needs so I'm all good, thanks for the help.